# What does Data Keyword do?

Tags: contract-development, python, serpent

`data domains[](owner, ip) # list`

Source video:

[image: Devcon 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is in Serpent.

```
data domains[](owner, ip)

def register(addr):
   if not self.domains[addr].owner:
      self.domains[addr].owner = msg.sender
```

The keyword [data](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Serpent#storage-data-structures) declares a variable with persistant storage. In the example it is declaring an array of tupples, each tupple has two members owner and ip.

For more info check the [A Programmer's Guide to Ethereum and Serpent](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~elaine/smartcontract/guide.pdf).